# Mostrar Item si es True en Array Json

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Como hago para mostrar el contenido de una persona si por lo menos alguno de los `items` dentro del `array` tiene el estado `denied`, este es mi `código`.

 index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Refinanciador</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="app">
      <div class="row" ng-controller="appController">
          <h1> FUTBOLISTAS </h1>
           <ul>
              <li ng-repeat="data in datos">
                  <p>Nombre: {{ data.nombre }} <br /> Apellido: {{ data.apellido }}</p> <br /> Estado: {{ data.status }}
              </li>
          </ul>
          <div ng-if="showPersonDenied" style="width: 100px; height: 100px; background-color: red; text-align: center;">
              Aca va una eprsona con estado denegado
          </div>
       </div>
 </body>
</html>

</body>

</html><br><br>
```

app.js

```
var app = angular.module("app", []);

app.controller("appController", function ($scope, $http) {
   //vamos a hacer uso de $http para obtener los datos
   $http.get('data.json').then(function (data) {
   //enviamos los datos a la vista con el objeto $scope
   $scope.datos = data.data;
   $scope.personStatus = $scope.datos;

   if ($scope.personStatus.length){
        for (var i = 0; i < $scope.personStatus.length ; i++) {
            $scope.showPersonDenied = $scope.personStatus[i].status === 'denied';
        }
    }

 });   
})<br><br>
```

data.json

```
[
   {
      "nombre": "James",
      "apellido": "Rodrigez",
      "status": "approved"

   },
   {
      "nombre": "Zlatan",
      "apellido": "Ibrahimovic",
      "status": "denied"

   },
   {
      "nombre": "Lionel",
      "apellido": "Messi",
      "status": "approved"

   }
]
```

la idea es que esta variable $scope.showPersonDenied sea true si alguno de los `items` dentro del `array` tiene el `status == 'denied'`

Comment: Si no viene ninguno como `denied` no debes listar? la idea entonces es solo listar los usuarios con ese estado?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si quieres listar SOLO los con el estado `denied` puedes utilizar `$filter`

```
$scope.personStatus = $scope.datos;
$scope.personDenied = $filter('filter')($scope.personStatus, { status: "denied" });
```

Y solo haces un `ng-repeat` de tu arreglo `$scope.personDenied` asi :

```
<li ng-repeat="usuarios in personStatus" ng-show="personDenied.length > 0">
```

Asi controlas que si no hay ninguno no se muestra la lista con `ng-show`.

Comment: la idea no es listar, la idea es mostrar contenido si existe un item denegado dentro del objeto.

Comment: @Pablo edite mi respuesta, con filter sabras si hay o no elementos con ese estado dentro de tu arreglo

Comment: @sioesi he editado tu respuesta y me he dado cuenta que estaba correcta. Lo siento. No había visto la aclaracion de Pablo. Lo siento.

Comment: @Naimad no hay problema! Saludos

Comment: @sioesi excelente me sirvio muchas gracias :)

Answer (score 0):

Bueno solo tienes que Agregar un ng-if para validar la condición, deberia quedar asi:

`<li ng-repeat="data in datos" ng-if="data.status == 'approved'">...<li>`

Aquí puedes leer un poco mas de sobre ng-if: [ng-if](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf)